# Is there any Rest Api which can Create Deployment Center at Azure portal in Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create Resources group, WebApp plan service, Webapp through the Rest Api of microsoft azure,
I have created above services from RestApi of microsoft Azure, 
but i am unable to find, How to create Deployment center.

not getting any thing.

Comment: which source do you want to configure?

Comment: just want to create Deployment center by Code Or API, so that it can automate CI/CD through Azure DevOps.

Comment: When you create webapp correctly on azure, the deployment center will disappear in azure portal.

Comment: @JoyWang want to configure Github Repository to Deployment center at Azure portal.

Answer (score 0):

The Deployment Center is a centralized overview for all the deployment methods supported by your app and a guided experience for configuring continuous integration/continuous deployment. It's a service under Azure App Service.

Go to your Azure App page in the portal, you will be able to see Deployment Center, click it then choose GitHub and configure it.

[image]

And don't forget go to Github setting page **Authorized OAuth Apps**. For more details, you could refer to the official tutorial:[Deploy continuously from GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment#deploy-continuously-from-github).

For now, no REST api to configure Continuous deployment. If you are looking for other ways to configure the Continuous deployment, you could refer to the Continuous deployment [wiki page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#setting-up-continuous-deployment-using-resource-explorer), there are other ways to implement it.